# The details about 'copy' and 'retain'

Tags: objective-c, copy, retain

I'm study about the different between 'copy' and 'retain' in Objective-c. but, I got some doubt, why the 'copy' method doesn't open a new memory address?

```
    NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, World !"];
    NSLog(@"%p, %@", aString, aString);

    NSString *bString = [aString copy];
    NSLog(@"%p, %@", bString, bString);

    NSString *cString = [aString retain];
    NSLog(@"%p, %@", cString, cString);

    [aString release];
    [bString release];
    [cString release];
```

The results are shown below:

```
2014-09-29 17:30:52.730 SEL_Demo[987:303] 0x100301030, Hello, World !
2014-09-29 17:30:52.731 SEL_Demo[987:303] 0x100301030, Hello, World !
2014-09-29 17:30:52.731 SEL_Demo[987:303] 0x100301030, Hello, World !
```

However, I created a new Class named Person, and implemented the delegate  with this:

```
- (id) copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
   return [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];
}
```

then, in main file:

```
Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%p",person);
Person *aPerson = [person copy];
NSLog(@"%p", aPerson);    
Person *bPerson = [person retain];
NSLog(@"%p", bPerson);
```

then, I got the different results are shown below:

```
2014-09-29 19:02:50.248 SEL_Demo[1133:303] 0x10010a860
2014-09-29 19:02:50.250 SEL_Demo[1133:303] 0x1003007f0    //different memory address.
2014-09-29 19:02:50.250 SEL_Demo[1133:303] 0x10010a860
```

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are seeing the immutability of `NSString`.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323095/41747) makes note of an example of two separate `NSString` objects having the same address when allocated on the stack.  I would assume that `copy` and `retain` simply return `self` for immutable values since they can never change.

Comment: I'm confused about why 'bString' didn't have a new memory address.

Comment: Since `NSString` is immutable - it can never change.  There is no need to allocate a new object to represent the same immutable object.  In a perfect implementation, there would be precisely one instance of an `NSString` with the value of `"Hello World !"`.  Every time that the runtime detected a `NSString`, it could use the one and only instance with that value.  In the real world, however, an `NSString` implementation can always return `self` from `retain` and `copy` which is what you are seeing here.

Answer (score 0):

`copy` doesn't necessarily give you a new object. An immutable class can choose to implement it by giving you the same object, retained. You should not care whether it is the same object or not.